# How to conditionally add routes to Axum Router?

Tags: rust, rust-axum

I'm using `axum` and this code to create a server but I get an error:

```rust
use axum::{response::Html, routing::get, Router};

async fn handler() -> Html<&'static str> {
    Html("<h1>Hello, World!</h1>")
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let router = Router::new();

    router.route("/", get(handler));

    if true { // I need to check something here
        router.route("/other", get(handler));
    }

    axum::Server::bind(&([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000).into())
        .serve(router.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `router`
  --> src\main.rs:18:16
   |
9  |     let router = Router::new();
   |         ------ move occurs because `router` has type `Router`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
10 |
11 |     router.route("/", get(handler));
   |     ------ value moved here
...
14 |         router.route("/other", get(handler));
   |         ------ value moved here
...
18 |         .serve(router.into_make_service())
   |                ^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

I tried with `&router` but I still get the error. How can I fix this? Should I use `.clone()`?

Comment: Because `.route` takes ownership of `router`. Documentation https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/struct.Router.html#method.route

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this code it works:

```rust
let mut router = Router::new();
router = router.route("/", get(handler));

if true {
    router = router.route(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simplified code (Axum does the same thing). `route` takes ownership but also returns it.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Router {
    list: Vec<String>,
}

impl Router {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Router { list: vec![] }
    }

    fn route(mut self, path: String) -> Self {
        self.list.push(path);
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut router = Router::new().route("/1".to_owned()).route("/2".to_owned());

    if true {
        router = router.route("/3".to_owned());
    }

    println!("{:?}", router);
}
```

So you have to set `router` in-line, or make it `mut` and reassign result of `route` to `router` variable.